# Processo PHP para de funcionar após várias/simultâneas requisições em Ngnix

Tags: windows, nginx, php-fpm

### O problema

Eu criei um processo usando PHP para trabalhar com o Nginx assim:

```
@echo off
echo Starting PHP FastCGI...
set PATH=C:\nginx\php;%PATH%
C:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\nginx\php\php.ini
pause
```

Mas se ocorrer mais de 500 requisições simultaneamente este processo é terminado e não emite nenhuma mensagem de falha ou algo do gênero. Note que o processo do Ngnix continua a funcionar, apenas o PHP para de "trabalhar".

Para ser mais claro, este problema ocorre quando eu uso o `ab` para testar o desempenho das páginas em um servidor "ngnix", desta maneira:

`ab -n 1000 -c 10 http://127.0.0.1:8000/info.php`

Após executar o `ab`, eu tenho os seguinte resultado:

```
Completed 100 requests
Completed 200 requests
Completed 300 requests
Completed 400 requests
Completed 500 requests
apr_pollset_poll: The timeout specified has expired (70007)
Total of 503 requests completed
```

Depois eu vou verificar o processo PHP na tela do "CMD" e ele está com a seguinte mensagem:

```
Starting PHP FastCGI...
Pressione qualquer tecla para continuar. . .
```

Claramente que o "CMD" foi para o "PAUSE" pois o processo PHP terminou.

O que pode estar acontecendo?

### Segue minhas configurações:

- Ngnix 1.6.2
- PHP 5.4.12

*ngnix.conf*:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    keepalive_timeout  65;

    server {
        listen       8000;
        server_name  localhost;

        root        html;

        location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
            autoindex on;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
            fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+?\.php)(/.*)$;
            if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
                return 404;
            }

            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
    }
}
```

*php.ini*

```
[PHP]
engine=On
default_charset="UTF-8"
short_open_tag=Off
asp_tags=Off
precision=14
output_buffering=Off
zlib.output_compression=Off
implicit_flush=Off
unserialize_callback_func=
serialize_precision=17
disable_functions=
disable_classes=
zend.enable_gc=On
expose_php=Off
max_execution_time=60
max_input_time=60
memory_limit=128M
error_reporting=E_ALL|E_STRICT
display_errors=On
display_startup_errors=On
log_errors=On
log_errors_max_len=1024
ignore_repeated_errors=Off
ignore_repeated_source=Off
report_memleaks=On
track_errors=On
html_errors=On


variables_order="GPCS"
request_order="GP"
register_argc_argv=Off
auto_globals_jit=On
post_max_size=8M
auto_prepend_file=
auto_append_file=
default_mimetype="text/html"


doc_root=
user_dir=
extension_dir=C:/ngnix/php/ext/
enable_dl=Off
file_uploads=On
upload_tmp_dir=c:/ngnix/temp/
upload_max_filesize=20M
max_file_uploads=20
allow_url_fopen=Off
allow_url_include=Off
default_socket_timeout=30
include_path=.

extension=php_curl.dll
extension=php_fileinfo.dll
extension=php_gd2.dll
extension=php_imap.dll
extension=php_intl.dll
extension=php_mbstring.dll
extension=php_exif.dll
extension=php_memcache.dll
extension=php_mongo.dll
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
extension=php_openssl.dll
extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll
extension=php_pdo_sqlite.dll
extension=php_tidy.dll
extension=php_xmlrpc.dll
extension=php_phalcon.dll

[CLI Server]
cli_server.color=On

[Date]
date.timezone=UTC

[Pdo_mysql]
pdo_mysql.cache_size=2000

pdo_mysql.default_socket=

[Phar]
phar.readonly=0

[mail function]
SMTP=localhost
smtp_port=25

mail.add_x_header=On


[SQL]
sql.safe_mode=Off

[ODBC]
odbc.allow_persistent=On
odbc.check_persistent=On
odbc.max_persistent=-1
odbc.max_links=-1
odbc.defaultlrl=4096
odbc.defaultbinmode=1

[Interbase]
ibase.allow_persistent=1
ibase.max_persistent=-1
ibase.max_links=-1
ibase.timestampformat="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"
ibase.dateformat="%Y-%m-%d"
ibase.timeformat="%H:%M:%S"

[MySQL]
mysql.allow_local_infile=On
mysql.allow_persistent=On
mysql.cache_size=2000
mysql.max_persistent=-1
mysql.max_links=-1
mysql.default_port =
mysql.default_socket =
mysql.default_host =
mysql.default_user =
mysql.default_password =
mysql.connect_timeout=60
mysql.trace_mode=Off

[MySQLi]
mysqli.max_persistent=-1
mysqli.allow_persistent=On
mysqli.max_links=-1
mysqli.cache_size=2000
mysqli.default_port=3306
mysqli.default_socket =
mysqli.default_host =
mysqli.default_user =
mysqli.default_pw =
mysqli.reconnect=Off

[mysqlnd]
mysqlnd.collect_statistics=On
mysqlnd.collect_memory_statistics=On

[PostgreSQL]
pgsql.allow_persistent=On
pgsql.auto_reset_persistent=Off
pgsql.max_persistent=-1
pgsql.max_links=-1
pgsql.ignore_notice=0
pgsql.log_notice=0

[Sybase-CT]
sybct.allow_persistent=On
sybct.max_persistent=-1
sybct.max_links=-1
sybct.min_server_severity=10
sybct.min_client_severity=10

[bcmath]
bcmath.scale=0

[Session]
session.save_handler=files
session.save_path=c:/nginx/temp
session.use_cookies=1
session.use_only_cookies=1
session.name=PHPSESSID
session.auto_start=0
session.cookie_lifetime=0
session.cookie_path=/
session.cookie_domain=
session.cookie_httponly=
session.serialize_handler=php
session.gc_probability=1
session.gc_divisor=1000
session.gc_maxlifetime=1440
session.bug_compat_42=On
session.bug_compat_warn=On
session.referer_check =
session.cache_limiter=nocache
session.cache_expire=180
session.use_trans_sid=0
session.hash_function=0
session.hash_bits_per_character=5
url_rewriter.tags="a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=fakeentry"


[MSSQL]
mssql.allow_persistent=On
mssql.max_persistent=-1
mssql.max_links=-1
mssql.min_error_severity=10
mssql.min_message_severity=10
mssql.compatability_mode=Off
mssql.secure_connection=Off


[Tidy]
tidy.clean_output=Off

[soap]
soap.wsdl_cache_enabled=1
soap.wsdl_cache_dir="c:/nginx/temp"
soap.wsdl_cache_ttl=86400
soap.wsdl_cache_limit=5

[ldap]
ldap.max_links=-1

[geoip]
geoip.custom_directory=c:/nginx/php/ext/
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O `pm.max_requests` é geralmente configurado com um limite, pois após atingir este limite deve existir um evento que reinicie o FastCGI, isto costuma ser utilizado assim para evitar vazamento de memória em servidores (em um ambiente de desenvolvimento provavelmente você não irá sentir).

Você pode até definir o `pm.max_requests` conforme as necessidades do seu servidor e para reiniciar (no caso do Windows, dificilmente veremos servidores Windows com Ngnix, o exemplo é só para entendimento de como reiniciar o PHP), você pode criar um loop com `goto`:

```
@echo off

echo Iniciando PHP FastCGI

:nginx_loop
echo Reiniciando...
set PATH=C:\nginx\php;%PATH%
C:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\nginx\php\php.ini
goto nginx_loop
```

A cada vez que o processo `php-cgi.exe` é terminado, o `goto` reinicia ele.

Porém em um servidor de desenvolvimento, você não necessita limitar `pm.max_requests` e criar um loop, basta colocar o limite como "zero" (note que em servidores de produção isto pode causar vazamento de memoria).

> O número de solicitações de cada processo filho deve ser executado antes de cada nova execução. Isto pode ser útil para contornar falhas de memória de bibliotecas de terceiros. Para o processamento de pedidos não terminar especifique `0`. Que é equivalente a `PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS`. Valor padrão é `0`

Fonte: http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#pm.max-requests

Um exemplo com seria usar o `set` em um arquivo `.bat`:

```
@echo off
echo Iniciando PHP FastCGI...
set PATH=C:\nginx\php;%PATH%
set PHP_FCGI_MAX_REQUESTS=0
C:\nginx\php\php-cgi.exe -b 127.0.0.1:9000 -c C:\nginx\php\php.ini
pause
```